# Django Celery. How do I run task at exact time?

Tags: python, django, celery

How can I write a code that will run a task for example "everyday (or every 24 hours)at 3:20 a.m."?
The main problem is "3:20" part, how do I make cron task at this exact time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply specify the minute and hour that you want it to occur on, and use * for the other values. For example: `20 3 * * *` will run at 3:20 AM every day forever.

You can experiment with cron-schedules using this website to get a better understanding for how the syntax works: https://crontab.guru/#20_3_*_*_*

Comment: OP doesn't indicate they'd be running cron or anything cron-compatible.

Comment: OP says "how do I make *cron* task at this exact time". That to me is an indication OP is using cron

Comment: Ah, I only read the title and tags.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try! Btw English is not my native (obviously) and I am also new to Celery so I could ask the question wrongly. So I hope what you wrote is what I need. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Rin If it turns out to not be what you needed, I suggest you provide some of the code that you tried with. It makes it easier to determine what exactly it is you might need or if there's a more convenient/simpler way to do it. Best of luck!